# ios inapp purchases - getting exception because product is not recognized

Tags: ios, ios6

I am getting this exception:

```
2013-08-06 21:48:05.046 entrepreneur[13200:11f03] Not purchased: 1
2013-08-06 21:48:09.075 entrepreneur[13200:11f03] Buying (null)...
2013-08-06 21:48:09.077 entrepreneur[13200:11f03] Buying (null)...
2013-08-06 21:48:09.079 entrepreneur[13200:11f03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid product identifier: (null)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1691012 0x1123e7e 0x1690deb 0x3c7dc 0x18d5f 0x1a4be 0x1137705 0x6e920 0x6e8b8 0x12f671 0x12fbcf 0x12ed38 0x9e33f 0x9e552 0x7c3aa 0x6dcf8 0x14dbdf9 0x14dbad0 0x1606bf5 0x1606962 0x1637bb6 0x1636f44 0x1636e1b 0x14da7e3 0x14da668 0x6b65c 0x2a1d 0x2945)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Because the product seems to be nil. Here is how I put the product object together:

This is the method which is called when the "subscribe" button is called:

```
- (IBAction)subscribe:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *buyButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    SKProduct *product = _products[buyButton.tag];

    NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);
    [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product];
}
```

I am working from this tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

And I don't really understand how they can be creating the product object which seems like it would be empty. But when it is empty, it gives an exception down the line.

Is there something I am not doing quite right here?
Thanks!